# How do I create a custom Logic App connector that leverages OAuth authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-logic-apps

I need to create a custom Logic App connector and want to (conceptually) recreate the twitter connector that exists in the portal.

As part of setting up this connector, the designer will prompt you to login with an OAuth account and presumably that OAuth token state will be store somewhere.

**Question**

How do I design a similar extension for Azure Logic apps, where the OAuth token / permission is saved properly within the designer?

In my case, I need a Twitter "@mention" rather than a hashtag alert (among many other extensions) and literally am rewriting the Twitter extension.

Comment: Currently custom connectors are not supported. An alternative would be to deploy a web app with your costume code and use the http + swagger card to consume it within logic apps. The drawback is that you would need to manage auth configuration externally. For any missing functionality in existing connectors, feel free to submit feature requests via azure feedback portal: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps

Comment: This has recently changed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/connectors/custom-connectors/define-openapi-definition